# Solving an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck style SDE

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

> Solve the SDE $dN=a N \log(\frac MN)dt+\sigma NdB_t,$ where  $M,a \in \mathbb{R}$.

Apply Ito's formula to $ f = \log(N)$ gives

\begin{align*}
     df &=  \frac{\partial f}{\partial N} dN +\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial N^2} d\langle N\rangle_t\\
    &= \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial N}aN\log\left(\frac MN\right) +\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial N^2} \right)dt + \frac{\partial f}{\partial N}\sigma  dB_t\\
&=a \log\left(\frac {M}{N}\right)dt+\sigma dB_t - \frac{\sigma^2}{2}dt\\
&=\left(alog(M) - af -\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)dt - \sigma dB_t
    \end{align*}
which looks like an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck SDE. How can I proceed from here?

Comment: Are you looking for exact solution?

Comment: @Khosrotash Yes i am. In integral form is fine

Comment: I think it has a typo ,must like $$\frac{dN}{dt}=a N \log(\frac MN)+\sigma N\frac{dB_t}{dt},$$?!

Comment: You're right it was a typo! I edited the question ..

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, what I write can help. but I'll try it.
rewrite as $$\frac{dN}{N}=a(\log M -\log N)dt+\sigma.dB_t\\
d(\log N)=a(\log M -\log N)dt+\sigma.dB_t$$this equation is very similar to mean-revert SDE's $dx_t=(\mu-x_t)dt+\sigma.dB_t$

Comment: Yes exactly, this is the OU equation I referred to. My problem was how to solve this based on the similarity